# Is it possible to make a while error or while no error Matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop, try-catch

In my matlab script i'm parsing a text file with a specific tag  structure and creating Simulink Block for each occurence of a special  Tag i found.  A simple example i have this :

```
[Link]
  Link_Name : On/Off 
  Link_ID : _sZfSkku9Eemg_bhrv2HEbw

[Link] 
  Link_Name : On/Off
  Link_ID : _qsYbsVeeEemna8dVWPKMTw
```

You can see that this is not the same Object but they have the same  name and so when in matlab i create a simulink block for each Link i  found i have an error `"can't create a new On/Off Block"` something like that.

So i put the ID in the description of the Block and if it's the same i just update the name in case of if the user changed the name in the text file :
  `set_param(gcb,'Name', link_NameValue);`

If it's different i create a new Block :

`add_block('simulink/Ports & Subsystems/In1',[component_NameValue '/' link_NameValue], 'MakeNameUnique', 'on');`

The problem is with `'MakeNameUnique', 'on'` it will create an infinity of Block if i run my script many times and with `set_param` i have an error 
`The name 'On_Off' already exists`

So i would like to make a while loop like this :

```
while error "can't create a new block"  
    add a "x" at the end of the name of the new block
end
or
while error "The name 'On_Off' already exists"
    add a "x" at the end of the name of the existing block 
end
```

So even if i have 4 [Link] with the name On/Off it will create  On/Off, On/Offx, On/Offxx, On/Offxxx or with number at the end if it's  possible.

Thanks for helping ! I tried to explain as short as i could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do some test with `try, catch` method. As you didn't give us MCVE so I can only give you untested code:

```
i=0
While i==0
    i=1 %An assumption that code will pass
    try
        sim('ModelName', ParamStruct);
    catch SimErr
        i=0
        %change some parameters in your model below
        %add a "x" at the end of the name of the new block or whatever you need
    end
end
```

So bassically  - if there is no error, `i` will stay changed to 1 and brake the loop. If the error will occur - it will also change back `i` to 0, to keep the loop going. In the catch statement you can pass some changes to your model to try it with new parameters iteratively as long as it will not pass.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried like this :

    `trying = true;`
    `n = 1;`
   ` while trying`
       ` try`
          `  set_param(gcb,'Name', nameParam);`
             `trying = false;`
     `   catch`
             `nameParam = strcat(nameParam, n);`
       `  end`
`    end`

This is the same way i think.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the concept is the same. As long as it works for you, it's totally fine. Good luck!